# Google Cloud Run Authentication Service-to-Service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-authentication, google-cloud-run, google-iam

I have two services (APIs) deployed on GCP Cloud Run. Call them `service-one.myDomain.com` and `service-two.myDomain.com`. I would like service-one to be authenticated in calling service-two independently of what any user is doing.

I've read and implemented the instructions from GCP Cloud Run docs on Authenticating service-to-service (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service) but `service-one.myDomain.com` is unsuccessful in calling `service-two.myDomain.com` receiving a 401:Unauthorized response.

Any thoughts on how to get `service-one` to successfully call `service-two`?

### Here's my setup:

#### IAM and service accounts:

On google IAM, I created two service accounts and granted them both the "Cloud Run Invoker" (`roles/run.invoker`) role:
`service-one@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
`service-two@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

Inside Cloud Run I changed the service account from the "Default compute service account" to the service accounts I created. I assigned `service-one@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com` for `service-one.myDomain.com` and `service-two@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com` for `service-two.myDomain.com`

#### OIDC Auth token:

In `service-one.myDomain.com` I make a call to the metadata server to get a token (jwt) from the following url:
`http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=https://service-two.myDomain.com` with a request header set as `{'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}` The request is successful and the token I receive is decoded to have the following payload:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "9cef5340642b157fa8a4f0d874fe7543872d82db",
  "typ": "JWT"
}

{
  "aud": "https://service-two.mydomain.com",
  "azp": "100959068407876085761",
  "email": "service-one@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "exp": 1572806540,
  "iat": 1572802940,
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "sub": "100953168404568085761"
}
```

#### Http request:

Using the token I make a request from `service-one.myDomain.com` to an http endpoint on `service-two.myDomain.com`. I set the request header with `{'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}'}` (`{token}` is value of token).

#### Http Response:

The response is a 401 Unauthorized and my logs show the response headers to include:

`{'WWW-Authenticate': 'Bearer error="invalid_token" error_description="The access token could not be verified"'}`

With a content of:

```
"
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Unauthorized</h1>
<h2>Your client does not have permission to the requested URL <code>/health</code>.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
"
```

I'm stumped.... any ideas on what I'm missing to get `service-one` to authenticate to `service-two`?

Comment: Can you perform this command: `gcloud  beta run services get-iam-policy <service-two>` (replace service-two by the real name)? And also this command `gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy <service-one@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com>` (again with the right replacement)? Final question, do you use custom domain ?

Comment: So I feel like a bonehead, @guillaumeblaquiere your comment lead me to the answer. I am using custom domains. It does say in the documentation that custom domains aren't supported. After switching out my custom domain for the cloud run generated url, service-one was able to successfully make a request to service-two.

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer was to use the gcp cloud run generated Url as the audience in the OIDC token request. And relatedly the "aud" field in the jwt.

My discovery was that Service-to-Service authentication in cloud run does not support custom domains (myDomain.com). I was using my custom domain.

(I feel like a bonehead) thanks @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Correct, the `audience` parameter of generating an identity token _currently_ does not support custom domains.